# Process a form with Redux and React

Tags: forms, reactjs, redux

I want to process a form and post its fields. I'm learning Redux and I want to use it for the form processing. The question is: what should I do in order to accomplish this task? Should I put the fields as part of the object (state)? What do you suggest?

Thank you

Comment: Check out [redux-form](http://redux-form.com/) -- without that, yes, I would make the fields be state; set their value attribute to the state they correspond to, and set their onChanged or similar callback attributes to modify the state.

Comment: @mjohnsonengr have you use redux-form? What is the best option?

Comment: Yes, I work on an enterprise app using react and redux.  It has lots of forms so we use redux-form now too.  The first form I wrote was before we pulled in redux, and the mess that created is the reason we pulled in redux.  Later, a particularly messy form motivated me to find redux-form.  I haven't experimented with many other options because most seemed less well developed than redux-form.

Comment: @mjohnsonengr ok I'm gonna try it. Thank you

Comment: Don't be too quick to jump to redux-form. You might not need it and it's a lot to grok imo. You could start by storing intermediate form state in React state. Once the form field(s) are considered complete and valid, then set Redux state.

Comment: @RickJolly ok I understand. I tried that yesterday and it said that getInitialState() is just for React.createClass({}) and not for extend Component. What do you suggest?

Comment: Search the exact wording of that error and you'll figure out that you need to set your initial state in the constructor when you extend Component using ES6 classes.

Comment: @mjohnsonengr perfect! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do? If you want to stick close to the metal with Redux, I recommend [React-Redux-Form](https://github.com/davidkpiano/react-redux-form) as it allows you to define your own reducers and handle your data model the way you want to.

Here is a quick start guide: https://davidkpiano.gitbooks.io/react-redux-form/content/step_by_step.html

Comment: I'm trying to learn and use Redux from now on in my apps. That includes forms where I add and modify data from de DB. That's why I'm asking what is the best way to handle the redux form processing

Comment: Then React-Redux-Form would be the best way since it allows you to create reducers for each of your models, and dispatch form-specific actions, so if you know Redux, you will understand React-Redux-Form.